# How to implement Contrast-Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization using CLAHE in opengl or webgl?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, textures, webgl

I am trying to understand and apply CLAHE on my Grayscale and Color images. Also I found [this book](https://books.google.com.au/books?hl=en&lr=&id=CCqzMm_-WucC&oi=fnd&pg=PR11&dq=Contrast+Limited+Adaptive+Histogram+Equalization+Graphics+Gems+IV&ots=mtft15JJbl&sig=acQg6XLt7jzqR0MjO6sYUa0Sjtc#v=onepage&q=Contrast%20Limited%20Adaptive%20Histogram%20Equalization%20Graphics%20Gems%20IV&f=false) on Page 478 , which helps in explaining CLAHE with some C++ code and [this tutorial](http://www.cnblogs.com/mikewolf2002/archive/2012/04/10/2439870.html).

I am very new to GLSL and unable to make a way with it . Can anyone help me to do that in OpenGL/WebGL? Also, I am not allowed to use OpenCV library.

**Edit:**
[This link](http://www.sci.utah.edu/~cscheid/spr05/imageprocessing/project1/) is even more comprehensive.

Even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527102/how-do-you-compute-a-histogram-in-webgl) is another perfect solution to Adaptive histogram but I needed the image by getting the ability to change the histogram.

Edit 2:
Somehow I was able to get CLAHE working in canvas 2d which obviously uses CPU, referring to this can anybody hep me figure out how to do the same in GPU?

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/abwLtneb/1/)

Code :
`

```
var iml = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
iml.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);

var cnv = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
var cnvori = document.getElementById('imageOriginalCanvas')
var ctxori = cnvori.getContext('2d');

function handleImage(e){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var img = new Image;

        img.onload = function(){

            cnvori.width = cnv.width = img.width;
            cnvori.height = cnv.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height);
            ctxori.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height);

            var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,img.width,img.height);


            var min=255, max=0;
            var intens=[];
            var levels=[];
            var j=0;

            for (var i=0;i<imgData.data.length;i+=4) {
                intens[j] = (imgData.data[i]+imgData.data[i+1]+imgData.data[i+2] )/3;
                j++;
            }

            var tilesize = [32, 32];
            var clipLimit = 0.1;

            // number of bins
            var num_bins = 256;

            var h = img.height;

            var w = img.width;
            // number of tiles in x and y direction
            var xtiles = Math.ceil(w / tilesize[0]);
            var ytiles = Math.ceil(h / tilesize[1]);

            var cdfs = new Array(ytiles);
            for(var i=0;i<ytiles;i++)
                cdfs[i] = new Array(xtiles);

            var inv_tile_size = [1.0 / tilesize[0], 1.0 / tilesize[1]];

            var cdf = [];
            // create histograms
            for(var i=0;i<ytiles;i++){
                var y0 = i * tilesize[1];
                var y1 = y0 + tilesize[1];
                for(var j=0;j<xtiles;j++)
                {
                    var x0 = j * tilesize[0];
                    var x1 = x0 + tilesize[0];
                    var hist = histogram(intens, x0, y0, x1, y1, num_bins, h, w);

                    cdfs[i][j] = buildcdf(hist, num_bins, tilesize[0] * tilesize[1], clipLimit);
                }
            }

            var finalArray = [];
            var p = 0;
            for(var y=0, idx=0;y<h;++y){
                for(var x=0;x<w;++x, idx+=4){
                    // intensity of current pixel
                    var I = Math.floor(intens[y*w+x]);

                    var tx = x * inv_tile_size[0] - 0.5;
                    var ty = y * inv_tile_size[1] - 0.5;

                    var xl = Math.max(Math.floor(tx), 0);
                    var xr = Math.min(xl+1, xtiles-1);

                    var yt = Math.max(Math.floor(ty), 0);
                    var yd = Math.min(yt+1, ytiles-1);

                    var fx = tx - xl;
                    var fy = ty - yt;

                    var cdf11 = (cdfs[yt][xl][I]) * 255 ;
                    var cdf12 = (cdfs[yd][xl][I]) * 255;
                    var cdf21 = (cdfs[yt][xr][I]) * 255;
                    var cdf22 = (cdfs[yd][xr][I]) * 255;

                    var Iout = (1 - fx) * (1 - fy) * cdf11
                        + (1 - fx) *       fy  * cdf12
                        +      fx  * (1 - fy) * cdf21
                        +      fx  *      fy  * cdf22;

                    finalArray[p] = Iout;
                    p++;
                }
            }   
            var pixelLength = h * w;

            for (var index = 0, indexToFill = 3; index < pixelLength; index++, indexToFill = indexToFill + 4) {
                var result = finalArray[index];
                imgData.data[indexToFill-3] = 0;
                imgData.data[indexToFill-2] = 0;
                imgData.data[indexToFill-1] = 0;
                imgData.data[indexToFill] = 255 - result;
            }

            ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0);
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]); 
}

var getInputArray = function(mArray, x, y, hDiff, vDiff, rows, columns){
        var inputArray = [];
        var k = 0;
        for(var i=x-vDiff;i<=x+vDiff;i++){
            for(var j=y-hDiff;j<=y+hDiff;j++){
                if(i>=0 && j>=0 && i<rows && j<columns){
                    inputArray[k] = mArray[i][j];
                }else{
                    inputArray[k] = 0;
                }
                k++;
            }
        }
        var finalResult = getHEArray(inputArray, x, y, mArray);
        return finalResult;
    }

    // build cdf from given pdf
    function buildcdf(hist, num_bins, num_pixels, clipLimit){
        var excess = 0;
        for(var i=0;i<num_bins;++i){
            hist[i] = hist[i] / num_pixels;
            if(hist[i]>clipLimit){
                excess = excess + hist[i] - clipLimit;
                hist[i] = clipLimit;
            }
        }
        var addExcess = excess/num_bins;
        var cumuhist = [];
        cumuhist[0] = hist[0] + addExcess;
        for(var i=1;i<num_bins;++i)
            cumuhist[i] = cumuhist[i-1] + hist[i] + addExcess;

        return cumuhist;
    }

    function histogram(intens, x1, y1, x2, y2, num_bins, h, w){
        var hist = [];
        for(var i=0;i<num_bins;++i)
            hist[i] = 0;

        for(var y=y1;y<y2;++y){
            for(var x=x1;x<x2;++x){
                var idx;
                if(x>=w && y<h){
                    idx = (y * w + (w - 1));
                }else if(y>=h && x<w){
                    idx = ((h-1) * w + x);
                }else if(y>=h && x>=w){
                    idx = (h * w) - 1;
                }else{
                    idx = (y * w + x);
                }
                var val = Math.floor(intens[idx]);
                hist[val]++;
            }
        }
        return hist;
    }
```

`

Comment: homework question + what have you tried ?

Comment: I have no idea on GLSL , however I tried and am able to render a image using the fragment shader and vertex shader but have no idea on how to apply CLAHE , I think it is very complex for a beginner in graphics

Comment: I don't know what a CLAHE is but there's this for a plain histogram http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527102/how-do-you-compute-a-histogram-in-webgl

Comment: @gman please check [this](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/adapthisteq.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) . It is a matlab explanation on CLAHE

Comment: @gman your answer is very helpful , I was just wandering if we could change histogram and see the changes to the real image at the same time . What you have done is  very much near to CLAHE. I am sure if you go through [these videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=clahe) , you would be able to crack it...

Comment: This is not a homework question. I need to do this professionally.

Comment: Already done long back  Thanks for the concern anyways